# How do I prove sin(10*sinx) and (x^(1/2))*sinx are/are not uniformly continuous on (0,∞ ) with delta and epsilon?

Tags: real-analysis

I know thah sinx and x^(1/2) are uniformly continuous functions, so 10*sinx is uniformly continuous too. But I don't know, how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a result which states that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on two overlapping intervals, then it is uniformly continuous on the union of those intervals. For $f(x)=\sin(\sin(10x))$, we know that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $( 0,1\rbrack$ since $f$ is continuous on $\lbrack 0,1\rbrack$. For $f$ on $\lbrack 1,\infty)$, note that $|\sin(y_1)-\sin(y_2)|\leq |y_1-y_2|$ (proved using the Mean Value Theorem); so we have
$$\begin{align*}
|\sin(\sin(10x))-\sin(\sin(10y))|\leq|\sin(10x)-\sin(10y)|\leq |10x-10y|<\epsilon
\end{align*}$$ which is uniformly continuous for $\delta:=\frac{\epsilon}{10}$. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1\rbrack\cup\lbrack 1,\infty)=(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @kimchilover Yes you are right. Here is the corrected version.